# React native: how to load AppRegistry component due to AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to load AppRegistry component due to AsyncStorage
this is the code in `index.js`:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import index from './src/pages/LoginPage';
import HomeScreenRouter from './src/pages/CategoriesPage/index';

let page;

AsyncStorage.getItem("@token").then((value) => {
    const token = value;
    if(value === null) {
        page = index;
    } else {
        page = HomeScreenRouter;
    }
})
.then(res => {

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('fatima2', () => page );
```

but I have an error that the app . doesn't found the AppRegistry component,
what should i do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Corret usage of AsyncStorge is like that:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('item', (err,result) => {
     //Do your logic here
})
```

i dont know the main problem is this but, your usage may cause some issues.

Comment: the same error: Module appRegistry  is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Answer (score 0):

Register a [StactNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack)
in your AppRegistry. Add a new dummy page with empty view at the top of the navigator. So, when the app is opened the "DummyPage" will be displayed. At this stage, the StackNavigator will contain three pages i.e "DummyPage", "Index" and "HomeScreenRouter". Then read the value from Async Storage and on it's callback [Reset your navigation stack](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#Reset)
.
Then your StackNavigator will contain either "Index" or "HomeScreenRouter" screen.